# How do I chose between upstart, runit, supervisor, daemontools, ... for restarting a process if it dies? (process supervision / monitoring)

Tags: upstart, supervisord, daemontools, runit

I have a Nginx web proxy, gunicorn web server, and a python/flask web app. The Gunicorn process apparently died, and I want to ameliorate that in the future by looking into a utility that can monitor and restart the gunicorn process in the event it crashes again.

I've found several process supervision utilities that can do the job:

- daemontools
- launchd
- runit
- s6
- supervisor
- SystemD
- upstart
- ...

Is there a comprehensive article that compares and contrasts the various utilities used to monitor and restart a process?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision

Comment: You should really be monitoring these services from outside the box, as situations *will* arise where you get into a restart loop and consume all of the available resources on your server.

Comment: Write your own code to do it exactly the way you want. It's an easy task.

Answer (score 3):

- `runit` is a successor to `daemontools` (both are written in `c`)
- `supervisord` uses `python`.

I've been using `runit` with `socklog` by the same author inside [Alpine Linux](http://alpinelinux.org/) `lxc` containers for around 10 months to manage `web` / `database` & various other services. It is light, easy to manage & I have had no service failures. The logging daemon also runs as it's own user & not `root` which is nice.

[voidlinux](http://www.voidlinux.eu/) uses `runit` as it's `init` system & also for [service supervision](https://github.com/voidlinux/void-packages/tree/master/srcpkgs) (search the package tree for `run` files for examples of `runit` scripts).

Answer (score 2):

If your distro uses Upstart, go with it. It has very basic support for job restarting, but includes limits that can prevent from restart loop, as mentioned by @EEAA.

If your OS uses another init program, don't change it. I can't really help you with the other tools you mentioned, as I generally use Ubuntu where Upstart is still present (as of the latest LTS), so I have little to do with them. But it's not a hard task to create a simple script which is run from *cron* once a minute (or more frequently in ie. a loop), which can check if a PID exists and issue restart on failure.